# Can i enrol both developer and enterprise account license with the same Apple ID?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, enterprise, account

Now i have the Apple developer program license , i need to buy an enterprise developer program license. I am getting struggle in enroll the  enterprise developer program license. Its always showing

> Sorry, you can’t enroll at this time.
>   Your Apple ID is already associated with a Team Agent enrolled in this program. If you have any questions, contact us.

when i try to enrol from my apple developer account ID. Now i need to known its possible to get the enrollment for both the developer account and the enterprise developer account with the same apple ID?

Please help if anyone known about this.!

Comment: *"If you have any questions, contact us."* - did you try that? "us" being apple, not SO in this context.

Comment: no @luk2302  not yet tried.!. Are you known can the same apple developer Id can able to buy the enterprise account at $299 ? bcz i am already have the developer account for $99 i need to use that same developer ID for enterprise too.!

Comment: Just create another Apple ID. It is just an email address. A single Apple ID can be a member of multiple teams but can't be the team agent for more than one

Comment: Thank you. ok @Paulw11. After creating the new apple Id, Can i add that account in to developer account like a team agent?

Comment: You could add your new Apple ID to your existing individual team with a role, but it can't be the team agent.

Comment: Oh thank you @Paulw11

Comment: I can't even get one account to work! Getting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51848371/developer-account-error-sorry-you-can-t-enroll-at-this-time) error.