# Developer account error: Sorry, you can’t enroll at this time.

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm trying to set up my own paid developer account to publish my first app. When I'm doing it I think I first have to enroll but then I get this error:

> Sorry, you can’t enroll at this time.

Does anybody know, why that error is shown? My only explanation would be, that I'm not 18 years old. What should I do instead?

Comment: You will need to get an adult, such as a parent, to enroll in the program on your behalf. A paid developer account requires agreeing to legal terms and conditions and signing contracts, so Apple requires you to be at least 18

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a software development question as defined in the [help]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must be at least 18 years old to have an organizational developer account, and 13 years old to enroll as an individual. To see a full chart explaining the requirements and benefits, see [Apple's website](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/).

Comment: For a paid individual (which is what the OP wants) you must also be 18. For a free individual membership you must be 13.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue and my account details clearly states that I'm over 18 but I'm still getting "Sorry, you can’t enroll at this time." when enrolling. How do I solve this? I've sent an email to Apple support but they haven't responded yet. Please help!!!

Comment: @ChiragMS, same is the case with me. Did you get any reply? Could you please share their support email id?

Comment: @KrupalGhorpade Sure. Click on [this](https://developer.apple.com/contact/#!/topic/SC1101/subtopic/30006/solution/select) link and select email option. And I didn't get any solutions to this yet. This has become a headache for me!! Apple support is completely useless in this case and there is no specific error or steps mentioned anywhere on the web to solve this issue! I'm so frustrated right now. I can't believe Apple is not at all paying attention to this. If you find a solution to this, Please kindly let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Hey guys did you all succeed with this issue ?

Comment: Did any one find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You must be at least 18 years old, if mistakenly entered wrong dob, you can edit your dob linked with your Apple ID here:
https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage